# pseudo random number generation

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I am generating a random number in my game using:

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random ();
int TileType = rnd.Next (0, 8);
```

The problem is that the numbers are too random. The numbers relate to tiles and i didn't get a particular tile for 20 rolls.

I need guidance on making a function that is generates "fake" random numbers. So basically I would like to make sure i generate each tile type in x rolls. I imagine 12 might be a good starting point for x but would like to be able to adjust x.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Heres what i am currently thinking. Thanks @Golo for pointing me this way. Thoughts?

1. Create a list of the numbers i want.
2. Add x more random numbers.
3. Shuffle list -var shuffledList = unshuffledList.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToList();
4. Grab the first item and remove from list.
5. Recreate list when empty.

This should mean that all numbers will come up frequently but you can still have repeats so it will maintain a random feel.

Comment: You are looking for "shuffle" OR "weighted random numbers" (depending on your preferences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list with the numbers you want to have, and then randomly select an element from this list and remove it.

Repeat this until your list is empty, and start over again.

This way you will get each number once in `n` tries, but their order will be random.

Comment: Nice. The only thing (if i understood OP correctly) that the n (8) is different from x (12).

Comment: Or use any other shuffle code (select and remove is easy to code, but can have very questionable performance for large lists due to large number of copy operations).

Comment: Getting close except I will not see value n again until all other values are have been rolled. I don't think i would be happy with this.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Golo's answer, but just to add a different spin on it . . .

It sounds like his response will only give you each value once. (ie:  You will not see value n again until all other values are "rolled" once.)

To keep things truly random while slightly more predictable, try a weighted random number generator.

After each selection, you can 0 out the weight of the selected item (decreasing the chance of it being selected next, and increasing the chance of selecting the "oldest" unselected values.)

These aren't in .Net, but should get you started on the algorithm.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=242744 
http://peterkellyonline.blogspot.com/2012/02/weighted-random-selection-in-php.html